# How to return the matrix of points that fall in a confidence ellipse?

Tags: r, ellipse

I have a sample of n pairs data from multivariate distribution. And I can easliy draw the 95% confidence ellipse using:

```r
library(ellipse)
mu <- c(0.06,-0.13)
sigma <- matrix(c(0.06^2, 0, 0, 0.06^2), 2, 2)
ellipse(mu, sigma, npoints = 200, newplot = TRUE)
```

What I wish to get is a matrix of all the paired (x,y) that fall into the confidence ellipse. thanks!